# Redirect documentroot to another folder in conf apache or .htccess

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Good Day

I want to rewrite a url when request a subdirectory
When the user request

> 172.0.0.1/url

i want to rewrite to make this url point to

> 172.0.0.1/url/url

or the documentroot is in /var/www/html/url/url make this point to

> 172.0.0.1/url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to avoid creating a rewrite and a redirect loop. You can put this code in your root folder htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect /url/url/xxx to /url/xxx
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(url)/url/(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite back /url/xxx to /url/url/xxx
RewriteRule ^(url)/((?!url/).*)$ /$1/$1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` to redirect `/url` to `/url/url`

Just Create .htaccess file at `/var/www/html/` with following contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?url/(.*)$ /url/url/$1 [R,L]
```

This will Redirect all incoming requests at `/url` and redirect them to `/url/url`

But you cannot redirect requests coming at `/url/url` to `/url` Because we are already redirecting request at `/url`, this will result in catch 22 and browser will keep redirecting back and forth between `/url` and `/url/url`.

Comment: Two remarks here. First, your rule creates a redirect loop. Then, it is actually possible to internally rewrite AND redirect at the same time without having a loop. See my answer for more details